# Deadlock when running two go routine

Tags: go

Im studying Golang now on my freetime and I am trying sample exams online to test what i learned,
I came about this coding exam task but I cant seem to make it work/run without a crash,
im getting fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock! error, can anybody help what I am doing wrong here?

```
func executeParallel(ch chan<- int, done chan<- bool, functions ...func() int) {
    ch <- functions[1]()
    done <- true
}

func exampleFunction(counter int) int {
    sum := 0
    for i := 0; i < counter; i++ {
        sum += 1
    }
    return sum
}

func main() {
    expensiveFunction := func() int {
        return exampleFunction(200000000)
    }

    cheapFunction := func() int {return exampleFunction(10000000)}

    ch := make(chan int)
    done := make(chan bool)

    go executeParallel(ch, done, expensiveFunction, cheapFunction)

    var isDone = <-done
    for result := range ch {
        fmt.Printf("Result: %d\n", result)

        if isDone {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `executeParallel` blocks writing to `ch`, main blocks reading from `done`.

Comment: Unrelated to your deadlock: `executeParallel` is supposed to run a bunch of functions in parallel and return the first result returned - but instead just runs the second function (`[1]`) only and returns just that result.

Answer (score 1):

Your `executeParallel` function will panic if less than 2 functions are provided - and will only run the 2nd function:

```
ch <- functions[1]() // runtime panic if less then 2 functions
```

I think it should look more like this: running all input functions in parallel and grabbing the first result.

```
for _, fn := range functions {

    fn := fn // so each iteration/goroutine gets the proper value
    
    go func() {
        select {
        case ch <- fn():
            // first (fastest worker) wins

        default:
            // other workers results are discarded (if reader has not read results yet)
            // this ensure we don't leak goroutines - since reader only reads one result from channel

        }
    }()
}
```

As such there's no need for a `done` channel - as we just need to read the one and only (quickest) result:

```
ch := make(chan int, 1) // big enough to capture one result - even if reader is not reading yet

executeParallel(ch, expensiveFunction, cheapFunction)

fmt.Printf("Result: %d\n", <-ch)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/skXc3gZZmRn

Comment: No, the channel is buffered (size 1), so no risk of data loss.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func executeParallel(ch chan<- int, done chan<- struct{}, functions ...func() int) {
    // Only execute the second function [1], if available.
    if len(functions) > 1 {
        ch <- functions[1]()
    }
    // Close the done channel to signal the for-select to break and the main returns.
    close(done)
}

// example returns the number of iterations for [0..counter-1]
func example(counter int) int {
    sum := 0
    for i := 0; i < counter; i++ {
        sum += 1
    }
    return sum

    // NOTE(SS): This function could just return "counter-1"
    // to avoid the unnecessary calculation done above.
}

func main() {
    var (
        cheap     = func() int { return example(10000000) }
        expensive = func() int { return example(200000000) }
        ch        = make(chan int)
        done      = make(chan struct{})
    )

    // executeParallel takes ch, done channel followed by variable
    // number of functions where on the second i.e., indexed 1
    // function is executed on a separated goroutine which is then
    // sent to ch channel which is then received by the for-select
    // reciever below i.e., <-ch is the receiver.
    go executeParallel(ch, done, expensive, cheap)

    for {
        select {
        // Wait for something to be sent to done or the done channel
        // to be closed.
        case <-done:
            return
        // Keep receiving from ch (if something is sent to it)
        case result := <-ch:
            fmt.Println("Result:", result)
        }
    }
}
```

I have commented on the code so that it's understandable. As you didn't the actual question the logic could be still wrong.